# append xml-stylesheet to xsl transformation result

Tags: xml, xslt

I use an xsl stylesheet to transform a xml document into another xml document.

I would like to append a stylesheet to the resulting document, that is get a resulting document beginning by:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="Styles/3.0/style/exchange.xsl"?>
```

for me it sounds like a xml header, but I can't find the xslt instruction to output the `<?xml-stylesheet ?>` during the transformation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way in a suiteable position in your (unknown) XSLT: https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-Creating-Processing-Instructions

```
<xsl:processing-instruction name="xml-stylesheet">
  <xsl:text>type="text/xsl" href="Styles/3.0/style/exchange.xsl"</xsl:text>
</xsl:processing-instruction>
```